# Forcing the background to be a static background

Tags: html, css

I have a background created using the following css:

```
<body onload='javascript:initializeQuiz()' style='background-image:url("images/bi.png");background-repeat:repeat;font-family:Arial'>
```

It is a repeating picture of some "binary" (just a bunch of random 0's and 1's for a dramatic effect).  When I scroll, the background scrolls too.  How would I make the background not scroll but allow the text and images on top to scroll?

Thanks if you can!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `background-attachment:fixed;` to your style attribute:

`<body onload='javascript:initializeQuiz()' style='background-image:url("images/bi.png");background-repeat:repeat;font-family:Arial;background-attachment:fixed;'>`

Comment: I can't, stackoverflow requires me to wait before accepting an answer.  Please calm down =P **EDIT** Ok, now I can accept your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

[background-attachment](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-attachment)

Comment: Thanks for the help, you didn't exactly give me a ton of information in your actual post, otherwise I would have marked yours correct :)

Comment: Well I **could** have copy and pasted from the official specification (which gave full details and examples) *that I linked to*, but that seemed pointless.